# What is the best way to pass multiple queries in params from frontend to backend in React Router V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, query-string, mern

I am making an job search app with multiple tags to click to filter the job listing using MERN.
I am trying to pass multiple query strings to backend and filter the data, but I am not sure how to extract from params and destructure in backend. Currently I made the params into arrays.

Especially when I click two tools like "Vue" and "Sass", it returns `["tool", "Vue"], ["tool", "Sass"],` but I want to combine in backend like {tools: "Vue", "Sass"} to filter easily.

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Filterbar from '../components/Filterbar';
// import PhotosnapIcon from '~/images/photosnap.svg';
import { listJobs } from '../actions/jobActions';

import './HomeScreen.scss';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const jobList = useSelector((state) => state.jobList);
  const { loading, error, jobs } = jobList;

  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const params = [];

  searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
    params.push([key, value]);
  }); // this returns ["level", "Junior"], ["language", "JavaScript"], ["tool", "Sass"]

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listJobs(params));
    console.log(jobs);
  }, [dispatch]);

  const addQuery = (key, value) => {
    setSearchParams((prev) => [...prev.entries(), [key, value]]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Filterbar />
      <ul>
        {jobs.map((job) => (
          <li className={job.featured ? 'post featured' : 'post'} key={job._id}>
            <div className="post__img-container">
              <img src={job.logo} alt="photosnap" />
            </div>
            <div className="post__upper-container">
              <div className="post__company-container">
                <h2 className="post__company">{job.company}</h2>
                {job.new && <span className="post__label new">new!</span>}
                {job.featured && (
                  <span className="post__label featured">featured</span>
                )}
              </div>
              <h3 className="post__job-title">{job.position}</h3>
              <div className="post__data">
                <span className="post__date">{job.postedAt}</span>
                <div className="post__dot"></div>
                <span className="post__hours">{job.contract}</span>
                <div className="post__dot"></div>
                <span className="post__location">{job.location}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="post__lower-container">
              <button
                className="post__category"
                name="role"
                value={job.role}
                onClick={(e) => addQuery('role', e.currentTarget.value)}
              >
                <span>{job.role}</span>
              </button>{' '}
              <button
                className="post__category"
                value={job.level}
                onClick={(e) => addQuery('level', e.currentTarget.value)}
              >
                <span>{job.level}</span>
              </button>
              {job.languages.map((language) => (
                <button
                  className="post__category"
                  name="language"
                  value={language}
                  onClick={(e) => addQuery('language', e.currentTarget.value)}
                >
                  <span>{language}</span>
                </button>
              ))}
              {job.tools.map((tool) => (
                <button
                  className="post__category"
                  name="tool"
                  value={tool}
                  onClick={(e) => addQuery('tool', e.currentTarget.value)}
                >
                  <span>{tool}</span>
                </button>
              ))}
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

**jobActions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  JOB_LIST_REQUEST,
  JOB_LIST_SUCCESS,
  JOB_LIST_FAIL,
} from '../constants/jobConstants';

export const listJobs =
  (params = '') =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: JOB_LIST_REQUEST });

/// NOT SURE about the url
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/jobs?q=${params}`);
      dispatch({
        type: JOB_LIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: JOB_LIST_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

> *>backend>controllers>jobs.js : Not sure what to add and how to destructure array to find the listing*

```
import ErrorResponse from '../utils/errorResponse.js';
import asyncHandler from '../middleware/async.js';
import Job from '../models/Job.js';

// @desc Get all jobs
// @routes GET /api/jobs
// @access Public
const getJobs = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const jobs = await Job.find({});
  res.json(jobs);
});

export { getJobs, getJob, createJob, deleteJob, updateImage, updateJob };
```

Comment: Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What specifically do you need help with? Please [edit] and clarify the issue. If you question is simply "what is the best..." this is too broad, subjective, and not on-topic for Stackoverflow. Please narrow the focus of your question.

Comment: Just wondering but how can you edit my tags without my consent. Are you admin or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and pass it to `axios.get`, since you have key-value pair as an array.

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

const { data } = await axios.get("/api/jobs", { params: queryParams });
```

or alternatively you can also send it as object.

```
const { data } = await axios.get("/api/jobs", {
  params: { level: "Junior", language: "JavaScript" },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I still don't know how to destructure it. `const getJobs = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const tags = req.query.params
    ? {
        role: {req.query.params.role},
        level: { $regex: req.query.params.level },
        languages: [...req.query.params.language],
        tools: [...req.query.params.tool]
      }
    : {};
  const jobs = await Job.find({ ...tags });
  res.json(jobs);
` this didn't work.

Comment: Just try logging `req.query` to console. How is it?

Comment: It worked thank you. I need to refresh the frontend page to update the params :(